# changing Locale in Tapestry 4

Tags: java, tapestry

I have creating login page in that, I am taking user's prefered language from drop down list. After successful login, selected locale will be used rather than Browser's locale

For aformentioned scenario, I am tring below code

```
        Locale.Builder langBuider = new Locale.Builder();
        langBuider.setLanguageTag( getSelectedLocale() );
       getEngine().setLocale( langBuider.build() );
```

Even after this locale is not getting updated. I found that to make it effective from same request, I have to change recreate page with updated locale

```
       IRequestCycle requestCycle = getRequestCycle();
       requestCycle.cleanup();
       requestCycle.activate( "Home" );
```

but after adding this code Tapestry throws exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also facing similar problem. I have done little modification

```
IPage page = requestCycle.getPage( "pageName");
requestCycle.activate( page );
```

This works for me

Comment: Hummm. Even I am also unable to find its reason